# Outlook PowerShell script does not retrieve latest email

Tags: powershell, outlook, etl

I have a script that reads an Outlook folder for emails, selects the most recently received email, and saves its attachment into a dir.

It is not working properly - it seems as if it only knows which email to receive if I first open Outlook before running the script - otherwise, it thinks the most recently-received email is the one that was last-received when I had Outlook open last.

Is there some way to prompt Outlook to refresh before the script prompts the scan?

My code is below:

```powershell
$filepath = $args[0]
$account = $args[1]

<#
#file path
$filepath = "I:\folder"
$account = "account@host.com" 
#>

#set outlook to open
$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)

$Account = $n.Folders | ? { $_.Name -eq $account };
$Inbox = $Account.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'Inbox' };
$Data = $Inbox.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'Data' };
$f = $Data.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'MyTargetFolder' };

$email = $f.Items | Sort-Object ReceivedTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

# Log the email we are looking for, and mention attachments if they exist.
Write-Output "Last email received at $($email.receivedtime), attached file(s) are: (if any)"
$email.attachments | %{Write-Output $_.filename}

# If the email has at least one attachment, save them to the filepath.
if ($email.attachments.count -gt 0) {
    $email.attachments | %{$_.saveasfile((join-path $filepath $_.filename))} 
} else { 
    Write-Output "Latest email at $($email.receivedtime) has no attachments!"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need a

```
$a.Store | ?{$_.DisplayName -eq $account} | %{If($_.IsCachedExchange){Start-Job {$n.SendAndReceive($false)}|Wait-Job}}
```

in there to make sure that if it is in Cached mode it will Send & Receive before checking for the email. See Edit note below.

You may also want to make sure that the user isn't in offline mode with a:

```
If($n.offline){write-host "You must be online before performing this script" -fore red;start-sleep 5;break}
```

That way if the user is in offline mode it'll display red text stating they need to be in online mode, wait 5 seconds, and then break out of the script.

**Edit:** Thanks to Adi Inbar it will wait for Outlook to finish its send and receive process before moving on to make sure that you have the latest email cached before moving on. Thanks Adi, I had no idea about that command, it's pretty handy!

Comment: It think this is the solution, and nice touch having the script check that the account is cached before invoking **SendAndReceive**. Rather than giving it an arbitrary 10 seconds to complete, though, I'd recommend piping to **Wait-Job:** `[...] if ($_.IsCachedExchange) {$n.SendAndReceive($false) | Wait-Job}}`

Comment: @AdiInbar I'll be honest, I have never seen `Wait-Job` before. Is it really that simple, to pipe a command to it and powershell waits for that command to finish before moving on with the script? It looks to me that you have to start whatever it is as a PSJob for it to work with Wait-Job

Comment: Actually, it's not that simple...I had formatting trouble with the comment (it wouldn't recognize my code span) and edited it so many times that I ended up butchering out a crucial piece. **Wait-Job** takes a job object as an argument, so you need to start the command as a job. It should be: `[...] if ($_.IsCachedExchange) {Start-Job {$n.SendAndReceive($false)} | Wait-Job}}`.

Comment: +1 for contributing. Dmitry pointed out that my Outlook content resides on the Exchange server - it is not working in Cached mode. When the scheduler kicks this script, my computer is always locked (but not logged out). Usually, Outlook is not already open on my machine when the job runs. Is the equivalent of it being in offline mode? Is the reason why it is not picking up the most recent email? After all, Outlook is being opened by the script, so I think this should not matter. I also tested the script with Outlook closed, and it seems to work - just not when kicked by the scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a cached (as opposed to online) Exchange store? Try to turn caching off.

Comment: +1 for contributing. No, it is online. However, I went into Outlook Options and changed Send/Receive settings to schedule an automatic send/receive every 15 mins when Outlook is offline. I'm not sure if this will help. I still want to find a way to do this programatically because I want anyone to be able to kick this PoSh script via a scheduler without having to change their Outlook settings.

Comment: You can use Namespace.SendAndReceive or Namespace.SyncObjects collection to start the sync, but it will be asynchronous. So what kind of message store is it? In case of Exchange, why do you need Send/Receive settings? The messages are received by the server, not the local store. Which isn't even present if you are using online mode.

Comment: My Outlook/Exchange vocabulary/knowledge is very limited, so please bear with me. It is an Exchange message store. You are right - when I view Server Settings, the 'Use Cached Exchange Mode' is not even available to be selected. I wasn't / still am not sure how the Outlook content I see is stored - are you saying it all resides on the server? Or is it copied to my computer? I have noticed that clicking 'Send/Receive' sometimes does push new items to my inbox.

Comment: Do you mean 'Use Cached Exchange Mode' checkbox is unchecked and disabled? If it is unchecked, all message are stored on the server. if it is checked, the messages are still on the server, but Outlook uses local store (OST) which the Exchange store provider periodically synchronizes with the server. Do you also have a POP3/SMTP account in the profile?

Comment: Yes, it is unchecked and disabled. I don't have a POP3/SMTP account in the profile.